# OpenCv does not save images as it was constructed?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, numpy-ndarray, opencv, python

I am trying to save an image from a pixel array(numpy.ndarray). Suppose my pixel array is myArray. When I type myArray in Python interpreter, it shows value as:

```
array([[[154, 161, 156],
    [154, 161, 156],
    [154, 160, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   [[155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   [[155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   ...,

   [[187, 193, 188],
    [187, 193, 188],
    [187, 193, 188],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]],

   [[188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]],

   [[188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]]], dtype=uint8)
```

But, when I create a new image from this array by using `cv2.imwrite('abc.jpg',myArray)` and then read this image using `cv2.imread('abc.jpg')`, the new array looks different. It looks something like this:

```
array([[[155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   [[155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   [[155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    [155, 161, 156],
    ...,
    [152, 157, 156],
    [151, 156, 155],
    [150, 155, 154]],

   ...,

   [[187, 193, 188],
    [187, 193, 188],
    [187, 193, 188],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]],

   [[188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]],

   [[188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    [188, 194, 189],
    ...,
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193],
    [189, 194, 193]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This  because of the data loss while jpeg data compression. if you want save it lossless save it as lossless png.

[JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) (/ˈdʒeɪpɛɡ/ JAY-peg) is a commonly used method of lossy compression for digital images, particularly for those images produced by digital photography.

Comment: Thanks. It is what I was looking for :)